# $wpdb->insert query changes to SHOW COLUMNS query Output

Tags: wpdb

[image]
I am writing a query for inserting data in to database but when I am printing query at output it turns into "SHOW COLUMNS from tbl_name" query.
I am writing below query . But it executes like shown in image

```
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'fullcontact';
    $sql1=$wpdb->insert( $table_name1, array(
        'status' => $status,
        'request_id' => $req_id,
        'likelihood' => $likelihood,
        'photos' => $photos,
        'chats' => $chats,
        'websites' => $websites,
        'fullname' => $fullname,
        'familyname' => $familyname,
        'givenname' => $givenname,
        'organisation' => $organisation,
        'normalizedlocation' => $normalizedlocation,
        'city' => $city,
        'state' => $state,
        'country' => $country,
        'age' => $age,
        'agerange' => $agerange,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'locationgeneral' => $locationgeneral,
        'socialprofiles' => $socialprofiles,
        'scores' => $scores,
        'topics' => $topics
    ) );

    //exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $wpdb->print_error($sql1);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "printing query". What exactly are you doing and in what order?

Comment: $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'fullcontact';
  $sql1=$wpdb->insert( $table_name1, array(
   'status' => $status,
   'request_id' => $req_id,
   'likelihood' => $likelihood
  ) );
  $wpdb->show_errors();
  $wpdb->print_error($sql1);

Comment: i am printing this query by show_error() and print_error() function

Comment: I don't  quite follow what you are trying to do there. Why explicit print_error() with _result_ of your query?

Comment: can I mail you the pics  plz ? I am hard stuck at this..it wud be kind if you help me.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else finding this question. Wordpress seems to do a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` query before executing the `INSERT` query. If it determines that the `INSERT` query would fail/store bad data, for example because the given data types would not fit in the column, it does not execute the insert query at all and return false.

Check:

- Have you filled all fields that can not be null and do not have a default value
- Does the data type for every field match the data type in the database
- Does the data passed to the function violate any constraints? A string cannot be longer than the maximum length of the field you are trying to put it into. An integer field has a minimum and maximum value. Unsigned integers cannot contain negative values.

Comment: Exactly.. I had did this in past and it worked..!

Comment: Appreciate this note, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same Problem, the fix was i tried to add varchar longer than the database field can hold. When changed the DB it workled again

Comment: thank You but it did'nt worked for me..anything else please ?